# use javascript to set value of paypal hidden field to value of asp control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, paypal

I have an aspx order confirmation form.  In the code behind, content is taken from a database and assigned to the Text attribute of a series of asp:Label controls.  On the same page is the "Buy now" form for paypal.  What I would like to do is take the order cost from the database and assign it to the value attribute of the paypal form's "amount" input.  When I try to do it, the value keeps coming back as "undefined."

I have tried several solutions but none seem to be working.  Currently, the code behind assigns the cost to the Value of an asp:hiddenfield control, and the javascript attempts to grab the cost from that control and then assign it to the amount input.

Relevant code:

in code behind 
...

```
costContent2.Value = confirmOrderDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["orderCost"].ToString();
```

...

in page: 
...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setAmount() {
cost = document.getElementById("costContent2").Value;
document.forms["paypalForm"].amount.Value = cost;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setAmount()">
<form runat="server" name="paypalForm" id="paypalForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="costContent2" Value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="X5RRRCPCDL7D8" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
```

...

I have tried changing the amount input to an asp control but I still get "undefined" as the value.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. JS is case sensitive. You have Value and not value
2. View the rendered page. You will likely see ID="C100........costContent2......"

Use

```
function setAmount() {
  var cost = document.getElementById("<%= costContent2.ClientID %>").value;
  document.forms["paypalForm"].amount.value = cost;
}
```

and have a look at this article: http://jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

Alternatively set the value in the asp

`<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= someValueSetEarlier" %>" />`